# jQuery Documentation function notation

Tags: jquery

The on() function in jQuery Documentation is depicted as

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

Please tell me what does ( **[,** )  ( **][,** ) ( **],** ) indicate in this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` in params for the function means the param inside it is optional.

For `on`:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`
```

`event`: One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".

`selector`: A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is `null` or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

`data`: Data to be passed to the handler in `event.data` when an event is triggered.

`handler`: A function to execute when the `event` is triggered. The value `false` is also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does `return false`.

**Variants**

1 Neglecting all optional params:

```
$("tr").on("click", function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Using this you can `bind` event to the all elements provided in selector.

2 Using Selector:

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

This is `event delegation`. Using this, you can `bind` event to all the elements inside `#dataTable tbody`. Also, to the dynamically added elements inside `tbody`.

Reference: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

3 Using data param

```
$("button").on("click", {
    name: "Karl"
}, function(e) {
    alert('Hello ' + e.data.name)
});
```

To send the data to the event handler this param is used. This is an object that can be accessed inside event handler using `event.data`

4 Using all params

```
$("div").on("click", "button", {
    name: "Karl"
}, function(e) {
    alert('Hello ' + e.data.name);
});
```

Comment: Sir, I understand [] means optional but why is there a comma inside [] i.e. [, selector]. It should have been .on( events, [ selector ], [ data ], handler )

Comment: Then the comma would be required. ".on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )" minimum is ".on( events, handler )" your example minimum is ".on( events, [ selector ], [ data ], handler )" = ".on( events, , , handler ) "

Comment: @Ankit: You should **not** vote up other questions by a user, just because they helped you. You should vote on each post based on their own merits, not based on who the author is.

Answer (score 2):

It means they are optional parameters i.e. you can do:

```
$('my-cool-element').on('click', function() {
    ...
}
```

or

```
$('my-cool-element').on('click', 'my-cool-sub-element', function() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sir, your comment explained me everything. Thanks a lot. I can only select one answer but I will upvote your 5 answers and get you +50. Thanks Sir

Answer (score 1):

Params inside **[ ]** is optional, **events** and **handler** is required:

1. **`events`** is a jquery event, eg **.click()**, **.hide()**, etc. [jquery events documentazione here](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)
2. **`[selector]`** is a jquery selector for an **html tag**, eg **'div'**, **'img'**,
   **'a.someClass'**, **'ul li'**, etc. [jquery selector documentation here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
3. **`[data]`** is data to be passed to the handler in event.data when an event
   is triggered. eg:

   ```
   $( "button" ).eq( i ).on( "click", { value: i }, function( event ) {
    // to do
   });
   ```

   in this case **{ value: i }** is **data**. [jquery data documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/)
4. **`handler`** is a function to execute when the event is triggered, any
   jquery function

example:

```
$( "button" ).on( "click", "div", { value: i }, function( event ) {
    // to do
});
```

in this case "click" is  [event], "div" is  [selector], { value: 1 } is  [data], function ( event ) id handler

Note:
is more simply use this **.on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )** , it is used frequently.

example:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "p", function() {
  $( this ).after( "<p>Another paragraph! " + (++count) + "</p>" );
});
```

in this case "click is [event], "p" is [selector], function()... is handler.

[jquery .on documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Yes Sir, you most certainly have. Thanks have a good day Sir. I upvoted your questions and answers. Sorry for late reply